# how to get excel column number from column name using access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get the excel column number (index) from the column name.

```
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelBook As New Excel.Workbook
Dim ColName As string 

ColName = "sample name"
Debug.Print ExcelBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ColName & 1).Column
```

But this code is not printing column number.
I instead get runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.
How do i get return the excel column number from the column name?

Comment: What is it printing?  Also, do you have a defined range name in your worksheet?  I'd like to recreate to play with it but I'm not able to get very far.

Comment: Don't need an instance of Excel for this: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/07/column-letters-to-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [msdn documentation for the Range object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and the [Column property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198200%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

I believe you are confusing the "Header" name in your worksheet with the column's address.

The code below will return the column index.

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Column 'returns 1
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Column 'returns 2
' to do this by row & col index, use the cells object
Debug.Print Thisworkbook.worksheets(1).Cells(1,5).Column 'returns 5
```

Comment: For my given column name **sample name** , If it is exists in the **AF1** then i need to get the cell number or whatever named as range like (AF1). For that which one do i need to use

Comment: @vuyy1182 You would have to do a search to find the appropriate cell. Row 1 is not special. It is not a "header" or column name. It's just a cell with a value like any other cell. Please update your question with a clarification if this did not meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure f the full code, but it appears as though you are telling it the name and column #.

Try:
Debug.Print ExcelBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ColName).Column

Also, if you are in the active workbook and worksheet, try stepping through and do a 
msgbox Range(ColName).Column